# Change the colour of the buttons of the toolbar when using Quill?

Tags: javascript, css, quill

[Current toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHP5q.png)

Above I linked an image of how the toolbar currently looks like. I'm trying to make the colour of the buttons and the text in the dropdowns white.

```
var toolbarOptions = [
        [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, false] }],
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
        ['blockquote'],
        [{ 'align': ['', 'center', 'justify'] }],
        [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
        [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }]                  
    ];

    var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
        modules: { toolbar: toolbarOptions },
        theme: 'snow'
    });
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe buttons and dropdowns styles are customizable with js, but couldn't find that in docs. However, css is still an option - if that works for you:

```
.ql-toolbar .ql-stroke {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #fff;
}

.ql-toolbar .ql-fill {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: none;
}

.ql-toolbar .ql-picker {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement this into my CSS file but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try adding it at the end of your all css, maybe even into separate `<style>` element - just to test if these styles are overwritten.  Just for testing purpose, try adding`!important` after all values and let me know if there is any progress. I've tested these styles yesterday and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes, it did work when using !important after all values. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that I could help

Comment: You, my friend, is hero! Thanks!

Comment: I tried many ways but this is no doubt the most straightforward and useful answer. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
button:hover .ql-stroke,
.ql-picker-label:hover .ql-stroke {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red !important;
}

.ql-active .ql-stroke {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red !important;
}

button:hover .ql-fill,
.ql-picker-label:hover .ql-fill {
  fill: red !important;
  stroke: none;
}

.ql-active .ql-fill {
  fill: red !important;
  stroke: none;
}
```

Comment: It's ideal when you can add a little context/ understanding to the code that you share as part of an answer.